# Location Services Work But Not Once The User Grants Permission

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, fusedlocationproviderapi

So I used a tutorial and pretty much copied and only changed a little if the user grants permission the app works after the user leaves the app and comes back. If they open the app and grant permission nothing happens, also if they deny permission nothing happens.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ArrayList<Weather> weatherLsit;
public static int REQUEST_PERMISSION=1;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private EditText zipCodeEditText;
LocationDataService locationDataService = new LocationDataService(MainActivity.this, this);
FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.hourly_recycle_view);

    weatherLsit = new ArrayList<>();
    weatherLsit.add(new Weather(10, 6, R.drawable.cloudy_icon));
    weatherLsit.add(new Weather(15, 7, R.drawable.cloudy_icon));
    weatherLsit.add(new Weather(10, 8, R.drawable.cloudy_icon));
    weatherLsit.add(new Weather(60, 9, R.drawable.cloudy_icon));
    weatherLsit.add(new Weather(80, 10, R.drawable.cloudy_icon));
    weatherLsit.add(new Weather(20, 12, R.drawable.cloudy_icon));
    weatherLsit.add(new Weather(13, 12, R.drawable.cloudy_icon));
    setAdapter();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        locationDataService.getLastLocation();
    } else {
        locationDataService.requestLocationPermission();
    }
}

private void setAdapter() {
    WeatherAdapter adapter = new WeatherAdapter(weatherLsit);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,  int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION) {
        if (permissions.length >=0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            System.out.println("PERMISSON HAS BEEN GRANTED!");
            //do something permission is allowed here....

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please allow the Permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

}

for some reason, the onRequestPermissionsResult isn't being executed I've spent a couple of hours already on this problem, and for some reason, I cant get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting the permission check in the `onCreate()` method.

like following:

[image]

And change the permission code to the following:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        Log.i(TAG, "sdk < 28 Q");
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] strings =
                    {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)context, strings, 1);
        }
    } else {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                "android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION") != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] strings = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    "android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"};
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)context, strings, 2);
        }
    }
```

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults.length > 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: apply LOCATION PERMISSION successful");
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: apply LOCATION PERMISSSION  failed");
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == 2) {
            if (grantResults.length > 2 && grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: apply ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION successful");
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: apply ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION  failed");
            }
        }
    }
```